# Input from Windows terminal for Python script

Tags: python, windows, input, terminal

I am currently working on GT-suite (a multiphysics simulation software) and I want to be more efficient.
The software includes Python and an interface to write Python script and a console.

I would like to get an integer by the user, but when I use `input()`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call back)
  File «stdin» Line 29 in module
EOFError : EOF when reading a line
```

I searched a little and it seems that the console is only there for showing output and so I can’t input in it.

Is it possible to open a windows terminal when the function `input()` is read by Python, enter the integer in the windows terminal, press enter and then the integer input is read by the script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the GT-suite, but if it's true the console is only used for output (and it sounds like that's the case), then you cannot used `input()` indeed.

Using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to execute another script that uses `input()` will not work either, since the child process will not have access to the standard input if the parent process doesn't have it.

Some possible work-arounds I can think of are:

1. Look for an alternative way to get user input using the GT-suite software. If it supports such a thing, that would probably be the best and easiest solution. I searched for some information about it, but unfortunately couldn't find it. However, the website mentions a video in which "*a script executes based on user inputs (...)*", which *suggests* it should be possible (or I'm misunderstanding it). They also seem to have an API, but I couldn't acccess it without account. If you can find the API documentation, you might search for a way to get the user input.
2. You *could* create a simple GUI in Python, with a text input field for the number. That should work. However, this is not a simple/straightforward solution, and I doubt you will become "more efficient". But that depends on your use case and is for you to decide.

   There are many GUI frameworks, but if you quickly want to test if entering numbers in the GUI will be possible, you could use the following code:

   ```py
   from tkinter import *
   window = Tk()
   txtfld = Entry(window, bd=5)
   txtfld.place(x=0, y=0)
   window.title('Enter number')
   window.geometry("300x100")
   window.mainloop()
   ```

   This creates a small windows with a text field, where you could enter a number. It does not return the value to the main script yet. It's simply the bare minimum to test if such a solution would work in your situation. If this works, you could extend the script to your needs.